# jok3r.py: error: the following arguments are required: command

Tags: linux

загрузил jok3r, пытаюсь научиться пользоваться.
Делаю обычный запрос:

```
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[/opt/jok3r]
└─$ jok3r attack -t http://192.168.0.41
```

Но выдает такой ответ:

```
usage: 
python3 jok3r.py <command> [<args>]

Supported commands:
   toolbox    Manage the toolbox
   info       View supported services/options/checks
   db         Define missions scopes, keep tracks of targets & view attacks results
   attack     Run security checks against targets
   
jok3r.py: error: the following arguments are required: command
```

Что делать?
Новичок, линуксом пользуюсь меньше месяца, поэтому не знаю куда копать.

UPD:

```
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ cd /opt/jok3r
                                                                                                                                 
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[/opt/jok3r]
└─$ python3 jok3r.py attack -t http://192.168.0.41    #Но все равно выдает ошибку


                         `-:/++++/:-.    .-:/++++/:-`                                    
                       .:ohdddmmmmdd.\  /.dddmmmmdddho:.                                
                     `:ydmmmmmmmmmmmmm\/mmmmmmmmmmmmmmdy:`                         
                    `+dmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmd+`                     
                   +dyo+++oshmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmhso+++oyd+                    
                 -+-         .dmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmd.         -+-                  
                ``           `dmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmd`           ``                 
                             `dmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmd`                              
                             `ymmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmy`                              
                               .+dmmmmmmmmmmd+.                                
                                  /dmmmmmmd/                                   
                                   `odmmdo`                                    
                                     .hh.                                      
                                                       
                                                                  
                      ██╗ ██████╗ ██╗  ██╗██████╗ ██████╗                                                                        
                      ██║██╔═══██╗██║ ██╔╝╚════██╗██╔══██╗                                                                       
                      ██║██║   ██║█████╔╝  █████╔╝██████╔╝                                                                       
                 ██   ██║██║   ██║██╔═██╗  ╚═══██╗██╔══██╗                                                                       
                 ╚█████╔╝╚██████╔╝██║  ██╗██████╔╝██║  ██║  v3.0 beta 2                                                          
                  ╚════╝  ╚═════╝ ╚═╝  ╚═╝╚═════╝ ╚═╝  ╚═╝                                                                       
                                                                                                                                 
                 [ Network & Web Pentest Automation Framework ]                                                                  
                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                 
[*] URL given as target, targeted service is HTTP
[!] Unexpected error occured: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)                                                                      
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3361, in _wrap_pool_connect
   return fn()
          ^^^^
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 327, in connect
   return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 894, in _checkout
   fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 493, in checkout
   rec = pool._do_get()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 256, in _do_get
   return self._create_connection()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 273, in _create_connection
   return _ConnectionRecord(self)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 388, in __init__
   self.__connect()
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 690, in __connect
   with util.safe_reraise():
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
   compat.raise_(
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 211, in raise_
   raise exception
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 686, in __connect
   self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 574, in connect
   return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 598, in connect
   return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/opt/jok3r/jok3r.py", line 32, in __init__
   Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 4930, in create_all
   bind._run_ddl_visitor(
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3227, in _run_ddl_visitor
   with self.begin() as conn:
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3143, in begin
   conn = self.connect(close_with_result=close_with_result)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3315, in connect
   return self._connection_cls(self, close_with_result=close_with_result)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 96, in __init__
   else engine.raw_connection()
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3394, in raw_connection
   return self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, _connection)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3364, in _wrap_pool_connect
   Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2198, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
   util.raise_(
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 211, in raise_
   raise exception
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3361, in _wrap_pool_connect
   return fn()
          ^^^^
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 327, in connect
   return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 894, in _checkout
   fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 493, in checkout
   rec = pool._do_get()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 256, in _do_get
   return self._create_connection()
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 273, in _create_connection
   return _ConnectionRecord(self)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 388, in __init__
   self.__connect()
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 690, in __connect
   with util.safe_reraise():
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
   compat.raise_(
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 211, in raise_
   raise exception
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 686, in __connect
   self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 574, in connect
   return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
 File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 598, in connect
   return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

Comment: Попробуйте для начала всё-таки как там просят написать, с `python3 ` впереди.

Comment: ответил в посту*

Comment: Теперь файл с базой данных не может открыть. Я не знаю где он там указывается.

Comment: не знаю почему не открывает, когда пишу установить, говорит, что уже установлено. Какие могут быть причины, что открыть не может?

Comment: Может он её создаёт, а каталог с правами только на чтение?

Comment: и как это проверить? 
Ну если это и так, то что делать?

Comment: Ну там есть какая-то настройка БД в инструкции? Нужно найти, к готовой он БД из дистрибутива подключается или создаёт. Разобраться, где именно создаёт и дать права на запись в этот каталог. Что-то типа `chmod +w /opt/jok3r/` но может БД в подкаталоге создаётся, я ж не знаю.

Comment: порывшись в интернете..ну, я не совсем понимаю как узнать где jok3r хранит свою БД, если вы про это. ибо я даже не уверен правильно ли я вас понял. 

Пытался провернуть кое-что такое:

                                  
`┌──(k)-[/opt/jok3r]
└─$ sudo lsof -p 72375 
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.portal file system /run/user/1000/doc
      Output information may be incomplete.`

Но это вроде не то.